# How to make product image required?

Tags: magento-1.9

Currently creating a product doesn't need any image. How do I make it required? Using javascript is ok. I know how to do it with input text field, but image is quite different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add some class for the field `media_gallery_content_save` and then to validate it as you check it to be `!= []`. For example in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml` replace this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_save" name="<?php echo $_block->getElement()->getName() ?>[images]" value="<?php echo $_block->htmlEscape($_block->getImagesJson()) ?>" />
```

with this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_save" name="<?php echo $_block->getElement()->getName() ?>[images]" value="<?php echo $_block->htmlEscape($_block->getImagesJson()) ?>" class="required-entry-image" />
```

and in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml` replace this:

```
Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-super-product-attributes', '<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please select one or more attributes.') ?>', function(v) {
                return (v != "no-attributes");
            }]]);
```

with this:

```
Validation.addAllThese([
    ['validate-super-product-attributes', '<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Please select one or more attributes.') ?>', function(v) {
                return (v != "no-attributes");
            }],
    ['required-entry-image', '<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('This is a required field.') ?>', function(v) {
                return (v != "[]");
            }]]);
```

Of course it's better not to change it in the core files.